# PSUTIL: module 'psutil' has no attribute 'getloadavg'

Tags: python, pi-4

I'm teaching myself python with the aim of building a small, off-grid server for collecting/transmitting data on my rpi. One of the datasets I'd like to collect is the CPU load by making calls to `psutil`.

If I run the following code on the command line psutil returns data:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.getloadavg()
(0.26, 0.43, 0.63)
```

But if I try running it as part of my Flask app in Thonny/IDLE it returns an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'psutil' has no attribute 'getloadavg'
```

I've read through the psutil manual but can't seem to work out what might be causing the error. Any insight would be gratefully received - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are building your Flask app in a **virtual environment** where you have already installed latest **psutil** module. I am pretty sure you will not get any errors then. Also make sure none of your python scripts are named as **psutil.py**.

Please make a habit of using virtual environments to avoid these kind of issues if that is the case.